# How to grab a YouTube video as an object using JavaScript?

Tags: video, youtube

I'm trying to make extension for chrome. So far I'm able to retrieve information by using this code:

```
var id = 'HRRruUdE-9o';
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;

$.getJSON('https://noembed.com/embed',
    {format: 'json', url: url}, function (data) {
    alert(data.title);
});
```

But, I'm trying to make an attempt to grab a whole video and store it as object?

Comment: Did you mean _"...grab a YouTube video as a **JSON** object"_? That `noembed.com` returns a JSON object and you cannot have audio/visual data as an object (data can be put as entry inside the object but can never be the actual `Object` itself). If you're asking how to steal video from Youtube then the Question should be _"How to get MP4 from Youtube"_ and and that point you can create your own object with either MP4's URL or MP4's video bytes (in hex format entries) depending on what you want "object" to mean (url or bytes?).

Comment: Yes. actually I'm looking for your second opinion. a video will be stored as an object. In that case, should I download the video first then save it as object or any other different approach should I follow?
Thank you.